# 301 is not working on nginx server

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect, nginx

A magento website transferred to Nginx and my 301 redirects are not working here.

Previous URL:

```
www.domain.com/store/food/two-year-supply-of-glide-r-chow-glide-a-mins.html
```

New URL:

```
www.domain.com//two-year-supply-of-glide-r-chow-glide-a-mins.html
```

Initially my .htaccess was

```
Redirect 301 /store/food/two-year-supply-of-glide-r-chow-glide-a-mins.html /two-year-supply-of-glide-r-chow-glide-a-mins.html
```

and now I have convert it to Nginx server format i.e.

```
location /store/food/two-year-supply-of-glide-r-chow-glide-a-mins.html {
rewrite ^(.*)$ /two-year-supply-of-glide-r-chow-glide-a-mins.html redirect;
}
```

Which is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You conversion looks fine to me. sometime nginx server ignore `.htacess` file try with a new file named as `nginx.conf` and put your all htacess conversion in this.

**Edit**

```
    # nginx configuration 
location /store { rewrite ^/store/food/(.*)$ /$1 redirect; }
```

I think this might help you.

Comment: Thanks , But its redirecting to 

www.domain.com/store/food/two-year-supply-of-glide-r-chow-glide-a-mins/two-year-supply-of-glide-r-chow-glide-a-mins.html

Comment: @AyanSarkar : you want to remove categories from url? if yes then go to System => Configuration => Catalog => Catalog => Search Engine Optimization and set "Use categories path for product URL’s" to “no”.

Comment: well , its not the case , we already done it . and thats why we are 301 those url to new source url